# How can I process Image in Django

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

In my Django Application, I am using imagekit to process images in my model but any time I try uploading image error says: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'ANTIALIAS'. Initially, I never had issues with it but recently any time I try to save my form, I get that error. I have upgraded Pillow and used ImageFilter.MedianFilter() instead of ANTIALIAS but error persist. Someone should help with the best way of doing this. I am using Django Django==4.0.

See my Model code:

```
from django.db import models
from PIL import Image
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
from imagekit.processors import ResizeToFill, Transpose
from imagekit.models import ProcessedImageField
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible

@deconstructible
class FileExtensionValidator:
    def __init__(self, extensions):
        self.extensions = extensions

    def __call__(self, value):
        extension = value.name.split('.')[-1].lower()
        if extension not in self.extensions:
            valid_extensions = ', '.join(self.extensions)
            raise ValidationError(f"Invalid file extension. Only {valid_extensions} files are allowed.")
```

## Allowed Image extensions

```
image_extensions = ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png']

class ResizeToFillWithoutAntialias(ResizeToFill):
    def process(self, img):
        img = super().process(img)
        return img.resize(self.size, Image.LANCZOS)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    date_birth = models.DateField(blank=False, null=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    marital_status = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    home_address = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    state_origin = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=STATE_CHOICES)
    local_govt = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    image = ProcessedImageField(
        upload_to='profile_images',
        processors=[Transpose(), ResizeToFillWithoutAntialias(150, 200)],
        format='JPEG',
        options={'quality': 97},
        validators=[FileExtensionValidator(image_extensions)],
        null=False,
        blank=False,
    )
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email
```

See Form code:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='First Name:', max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter  First Name'}))
    middle_name = forms.CharField(label='Middle Name:', max_length=30, required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter  Middle Name'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Surname:', max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Your Last Name'}))
    phone_number = forms.CharField(label='Phone Number:', max_length=11)

    class Meta:
        widgets = {'date_birth': ProfileDateField()}
        model = Profile
        fields = ['first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number', 'date_birth', 'gender', 'marital_status', 'image']
```

See View code:

```
@login_required(login_url='accounts_login')
def applicant_update_profile(request):
    logged_user = request.user
    # Get the profile of the logged user
    profile = logged_user.profile
    if not logged_user.profile.role == 'Applicant':
        return redirect('accounts_login')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Profile Saved Successfully.')
            return redirect('accounts_profile')
    else:
        form = ProfileForm(instance=profile)

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'page_title': 'Update Profile',
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/applicant_update_profile.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because Pillow starting from version 10 doesn't have ANTIALIAS constant, which was [deprecated in 9.1.0](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releasenotes/9.1.0.html#deprecations).

You should try to update [django-imagekit](https://github.com/matthewwithanm/django-imagekit/issues/566) and [pilkit](https://github.com/matthewwithanm/pilkit/issues/64) to fix it.

```bash
$ pip install -U django-imagekit pilkit
```